# send data to controller by jquery jeditable plugin Code igniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jeditable

i have a data showing on my view page in a table .. i am using a jeditable plugin which is that if i click on lets say some text it becomes editable  and then i want to send the new edit value to controller . i dont know how to send the new values to the controller  ..this is what i am doing but it is not working .here is my view page..if it can be done through ajax then it ill be better for me..

```
   <?php foreach($records as $row){?>
    <tr>
    <td class = "click"><?php echo $row->cat_name; ?>  </td>
```

my javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.click').editable('<?php echo site_url('categoryController/editCategory');?>',
           {

         });

            });
```

Comment: Does this  <td class = "click"> contain the test that can be edited?

Comment: http://www.rspca.org.au/assets/templates/rspca/js/datatables/examples/api/editable.html